# Unable to compile typescript on heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku, typescript-typings

I am trying to deploy a typescript nodejs app using express to heroku, the code is pushed up fine, heroku installs the dependencies and then runs `tsc` but crashes with `src/controller/adminTypes.ts:3:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../repo/adminTypes'.`.

I checked the line where the import happens and it looks like this

`import { insertAdminTypes } from "../repo/adminTypes";`

The equivalent export happens like so

```
export const insertAdminTypes = async queryObj => {
  // code
};
```

VSCode resolves the paths perfectly fine, when I try running tsc locally everything compiles fine and I get the compiled files in the `dist` folder. It's only heroku that seems to be throwing an error for the paths online. This doesn't happen for every file, the above `TS2307` error is thrown only for a few files.

These are the following config files.

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "express_server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "./src/server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build-ts": "tsc",
    "start": "npx nodemon",
    "prod": "npx run build-ts",
    "postinstall": "npm run build-ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.22",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.2",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.9",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.9",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.8",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^1.1.3",
    "lint-staged": "^8.0.4",
    "prettier": "^1.15.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.8.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.15.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "linters": {
      "*.{ts}": [
        "npx tslint --fix",
        "git add"
      ]
    },
    "ignore": [
      "./public",
      "./environment",
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  }
}
```

`nodemon.json`

```
{
  "ignore": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts", ".git", "node_modules"],
  "watch": ["src"],
  "exec": "npx ts-node ./src/server.ts",
  "ext": "ts"
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "pretty": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: A standard troubleshooting step: enable the `traceResolution` compiler option and look at the output.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it turns out I wasn't paying attention to the filename ie, the case.

For example the error being thrown as described above `Cannot find module '../repo/adminTypes'` was due to the face that the actual filename was `AdminTypes`, capital `A`.

VSCode/ Windows was auto handling case sensitivity so it never threw an error but when deployed to heroku, the server was very strict with filenames.